# Python file doesn't exist--verified correct working directory

Tags: python, pandas

Reading a csv with pandas, I get the error: 'IOError: File /test.csv does not exist.' Here is how I am reading:

```
var1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

I verified that I am in the correct working directory with:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Which prints C:\Users\name\folderName, and the test.csv file is in folderName. I also check if the file exists using `os.path.isfile('test.csv')` and that returns false. What am I doing incorrectly? I have tried using the full path as well, it did not work.

Edit: I tried opening a .txt file with the same format and everything was fine, so the problem seems to be with the fact that I'm opening a .csv.

Comment: try using the complete path using the os module

Comment: Your error message says `/test.csv` but your code says `test.csv`.  Which are you actually using in your actual code?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am using pd.read_csv("test.csv"), and I verified that the error message does include the forward slash.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the problem is only with .csv files

Answer (score 0):

The correct path would be

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), test.csv)
```

`os.getcwd()` gives you the path C:\Users\name\folderName and then we join the filename to make the complete path.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "test.csv"))` returns false.

Comment: Use the complete path in that case. You may just be opening the shell in different locations.

Comment: I have already tried this (in main post) and I am printing the working directory to verify the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was file name 'test.csv' and type csv rather than 'test' with type csv.

Comment: Are you sure that you had a file named `'test.csv'` and that `os.path.isfile('test.csv')` returned `False`?

Comment: Yes. I thought this was strange as well and double-checked to be sure. With the same code, if the file directory is showing the name as 'test.csv' there is an error and the csv is not read. If the name is 'test' it works fine.

Comment: With filename 'test.csv' I can work with 'test.csv.csv'. I've never had a problem with anything like this before.

Comment: It looks like you are using windows explorer configured to hide extensions. See what `os.path.listdir('.')` returns. See: [Microsoft: Show or hide file name extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)